# Leaflet map - clustering with layer group, sidebar & custom icons based on this: https://github.com/handsondataviz/leaflet-point-map-sidebar

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling with incorporating a clustering (or spiderfying) to a map with image icons based on this brilliant template https://github.com/handsondataviz/leaflet-point-map-sidebar?
Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

I've re-read documentation and tried different versions of both leaflet and leaflet-markercluster but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you looked at the code of [the example](https://handsondataviz.github.io/leaflet-point-map-sidebar/), and the format (columns, content, etc) of the linked Google sheets file? Are you having trouble with something specific, or implementing this, in general? Please add more details.